# Fill datatable in a class, return table to use in another class

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Ok Title may not be clear so let me explain.
I have 2 classes, "Form1" and "webinfo".

in "webinfo" I run the following code:

```
class WebInfo
{
    string myConnVRM = "Data Source = datascource;" +
                          "Initial Catalog = catalog;" +
                          "Persist Security Info=True;" +
                          "User ID=ID;" +
                          "Password=PASS;" +
                          "providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;";
    public WebInfo()
    {

    }

    public void GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc)
    {
        DataTable vrmTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connVRM = new SqlConnection(myConnVRM);
        connVRM.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdVRM = new SqlCommand("SELECT Ac, Vrm, Make, Model, MamengineSize, date FROM ReturnValue WHERE convert(varchar,[Date],101) between @StartDate and @EndDate and [AC]=@Acct", connVRM);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", acc);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", start);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@too", end);
        SqlDataAdapter vrmAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdVRM);
        vrmAdapter.Fill(vrmTable);

        //bind to data grid and display??
    }
}
```

as you can see I connect to a server, run a query and finally fill my table with the results.

my form class then calls GetVRms method, passes the relevent info.

But what I need to do is now bind this table to the datagrid on my form so i can display.  Only problem is how do i use the table from this class?

Am i totally over thinking this?  is it as simple as webinfo.vrmtable?

Many Thanks In Advance

Comment: btw, you're going to bleed connections doing that - you should have `using` statements for `connVRM` and `cmdVRM`, to ensure they are disposed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    public void GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc)
```

to

```
    public DataTable GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc)
```

then put

```
    return vrmTable;
```

at the end of the method.

Then bind to the table in your UI like this:

```
    WebInfo wi = new WebInfo();
    DataTable dt = wi.GetVRMs(....);
    myDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    myDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: i dont know why i didnt make a return type for the table..... think its my brain failing today.  many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the intent. If that is a utility method, then make it *return* the data, i.e.

```
public DataTable GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc)
{
    ...
    return vrmTable;
}
```

and access as `var data = obj.GetVRMs(...)`.

If the table needs to be retained, then store it somewhere

```
public DataTable TheTable {get;set;}
public void GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc)
{
    ...
    TheTable = vrmTable;
}
```

and access as:

```
obj.GetVRMs(..);
var data = obj.TheTable;
```

notes:

- `GetVRMs` is perhaps over-abbreviated
- `DataTable` *works*, but a lot of people would suggest a type model is a better metaphor
- you need `using` statements etc to avoid issues (most obviously: saturating the connection pool)

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL seems wrong here as well.

```
   SqlCommand cmdVRM = new SqlCommand("SELECT Ac, Vrm, Make, Model, MamengineSize, date FROM ReturnValue WHERE convert(varchar,[Date],101) between @StartDate and @EndDate and [AC]=@Acct", connVRM);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", acc);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", start);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", end);
```

OR

```
    string SQL = "SELECT Ac, Vrm, Make, Model, MamengineSize, date FROM ReturnValue WHERE convert(datetime,[Date],101) between '"+ start +"' and '"+ end +"' and [AC]=" + acc+ "; ";
          SqlCommand cmdVRM = new SqlCommand(SQL, connVRM);
```

Now you can use it the way you like it.

```
// As DataTable is ref
public void GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc, DataTable dtVM)
{
if(dtVM == null) throw new Exception("Message");
   ......
}
```

OR

```
public DataTable GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc)
{
  DataTable dtVM=new DataTable();
  .......

  Return dtVM;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a public property vrmtable and access it from anywhere using object of WebInfo class.

```
class WebInfo
{
    public DataTable vrmTable{get;} 

    string myConnVRM = "Data Source = datascource;" +
                          "Initial Catalog = catalog;" +
                          "Persist Security Info=True;" +
                          "User ID=ID;" +
                          "Password=PASS;" +
                          "providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;";
    public WebInfo()
    {

    }

    public void GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc)
    {
        SqlConnection connVRM = new SqlConnection(myConnVRM);
        vrmTable == new DataTable();
        connVRM.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdVRM = new SqlCommand("SELECT Ac, Vrm, Make, Model, MamengineSize, date FROM ReturnValue WHERE convert(varchar,[Date],101) between @StartDate and @EndDate and [AC]=@Acct", connVRM);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", acc);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", start);
        cmdVRM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@too", end);
        SqlDataAdapter vrmAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdVRM);
        vrmAdapter.Fill(vrmTable);

        //bind to data grid and display??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply return the DataTable ?

```
public DataTable GetVRMs(string vRMs, string start, string end, string acc) 
{        
    [...]
    return vrmTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use return type as `DataTable` instead of `void` for `GetVRMs` method  to return table i.e. `vrmTable` and then assign it to datasource of datagrid